# Running function when string in list is different from string in previous value of list

Tags: python, list, function

I have a function which I would like to run every 10 seconds. This has a global variable which is a string called `marketId`.

At somepoint, this string changes. When this happens I want to run a new function.

To do this I have tried the following:

```
def test():
    print("working")


def loop():

    marketId_list = []

    while True:

        time.sleep(10)

        full_function()

        marketId_list.append(marketId)

        for i in marketId_list:

            if marketId_list[i] != marketId_list[i-1]:

                test()
```

But when I run the `loop()` function I get the error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str
```

Any help in solving this would be appreciated, cheers. Sandy

Comment: `for i in marketId_list` iterates *directly over the items in the list*.

Comment: Use [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) when you want access to an item's index while iterating. `for idx,item in enumerate(marketId_list): ...`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
for i, item in enumerate(marketId_list):
    if i>0 and marketId_list[i] != marketId_list[i-1]:
        test()
```

Comment: Or even `for previous,current in zip(marketId_list, marketId_list[1:]): ...`

Comment: Note: in the first iteration i is 0 and i-1 is -1 which is the last element of the list and thus the first element of the list is compared to the last element of the list which may or may not be intended.

Comment: @fabianegli you are right, i kinda fixed it, but my answer had to do with the error that he asked for. This is some other bug on his code.

Comment: @Thierry Lathuille you are right, but I intentionally left it that way so "i" and "i-1" are distinct.